# $.grep on JSON data in multiple array.fields using wildcards?

Tags: dictionary, filter, grep, wildcard

First off I have looked through similar looking questions but have not found the exact problem asked or answered, so here goes :

I have a JSON Object which consists of about 900+ posts. Looking like this:

```
 var JsonData = [{"rowNumber":563663,"hasWarning":true,"isInvoiceAccount":true,"phone":"","name":"Romerike AS","address1":"Co/Skanning","address2":"PB 52","attention":"","mobile":"","email":"fakt@bos.no","fax":"","zipCity":"N-1471 Askim","invoiceAccount":"","notes":null,"account":"3","country":"NORGE","salesRep":"4","countryCode":"no"},{"rowNumber":563674,"hasWarning":false,"isInvoiceAccount":true,"phone":"","name":"LILLEHAMMER","address1":"POSTBOKS 110","address2":"","attention":"","mobile":"","email":"","fax":"","zipCity":"N-2605 LILLEHAMMER","invoiceAccount":"","notes":null,"account":"14","country":"NORGE","salesRep":"4","countryCode":"no"},{"rowNumber":563676,"hasWarning":true,"isInvoiceAccount":true,"phone":"63929788","name":"Askim Bil AS","address1":"Postboks 82","address2":"","attention":"","mobile":"","email":"karosseri@nyg.no","fax":"","zipCity":"N-2051 Askim","invoiceAccount":"","notes":null,"account":"16","country":"NORGE","salesRep":"4","countryCode":"no"},{"rowNumber":563686,"hasWarning":false,"isInvoiceAccount":true,"phone":"69826060","name":"KAROSSERI A/S","address1":"POSTBOKS 165","address2":"","attention":"","mobile":"","email":"tkar@online.no","fax":"","zipCity":"N-1860  TR&Oslash;GSTAD","invoiceAccount":"","notes":null,"account":"26","country":"NORGE","salesRep":"4","countryCode":"no"},{"rowNumber":563690,"hasWarning":false,"isInvoiceAccount":true,"phone":"","name":"AUTOSERVICE A/S","address1":"POSTBOKS 15","address2":"","attention":"","mobile":"","email":"","fax":"","zipCity":"N-2851  LENA","invoiceAccount":"","notes":null,"account":"30","country":"NORGE","salesRep":"4","countryCode":"no"},{"rowNumber":563691,"hasWarning":false,"isInvoiceAccount":false,"phone":"","name":"&Oslash;YHUS A/S","address1":"POSTBOKS 321","address2":"","attention":"John Doe","mobile":"","email":"","fax":"","zipCity":"N-2817  GJ&Oslash;VIK","invoiceAccount":"","notes":null,"account":"31","country":"NORGE","salesRep":"4","countryCode":"no"}];
```

I want to filter these data before I read them into a table using $.grep.
The JSON data have been loaded as an object.
In the HTML page I have a textfield named "filter". 
The following code works, but only when I search for an exact match:

```
 var JsonFiltered = $.grep(JsonData, function (element, index) {
        return element.zipCity == $('#filter').val();
    });

  $.each( JsonFiltered, function ( index, value ) {
     // sorting through the array adding values to a table
    [...]
  });
```

Problem 1:
I want to use Wildcards when filtering.
I read something about using regexp but I haven't found any viable examples.

Problem 2:
I want to be able to filter more than one column. 
Example: filtering the word "Askim" in both element.name and element.zipCity

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the solutions myself...

Using Wildcards:

```
        var search_term = $('#filter').val();
        var search = new RegExp(search_term, "i");

        var JsonFiltered = $.grep(JsonTest, function (element, index) {

        var zipC = search.test(element.zipCity) 
        var names = search.test(element.name)
        return zipC + names ;
```

The solution was to use "new RegExp" with the filter "i" setting. 
then I took two search.tests combined them in the return command and... presto

Hope this helps anyone else.